# C# Determine EOL Character in flat files

Tags: c#, eol

I am attempting to identify what the EOL character is from a given .txt or .csv flat file. Based on what the EOL character is from the first row of data in the flat file, I want to process the data from this file accordingly (I am using Bulk Load to create tables on SQL Server and need to pass in the EOL to the bulk load command). From what I understand, Readline() handles the EOL automatically, so I can't parse the Readline() string for the EOL character. The code below gives an example of what I am trying to do:

```
int EOLChar_CRLF = 0;
int EOLChar_LF = 0;
int EOLChar_CR = 0;
int EOLChar_Hex = 0;

string eol_line = file2.ReadLine();
MessageBox.Show(eol_line);
EOLChar_CRLF = eol_line.IndexOf("\\r\\\n");
EOLChar_LF = eol_line.IndexOf("\\n");
EOLChar_CR = eol_line.IndexOf("\\r");
EOLChar_Hex = eol_line.IndexOf("\\0x0a");

MessageBox.Show("CRLF is line feed if " + EOLChar_CRLF.ToString() + " <> -1");
MessageBox.Show("LF is line feed if " + EOLChar_LF.ToString() + " <> -1");
MessageBox.Show("CR is line feed if " + EOLChar_CR.ToString() + " <> -1");
MessageBox.Show("0x0a is line feed if " + EOLChar_Hex.ToString() + " <> -1");
```

Does anybody know of a way to determine the EOL using the StreamReader.ReadLine() method or any other way of accomplishing this? I only want to read in the first row of data and parse that for the EOL since some of these files are 20+ million rows.

Comment: How can you determine the first "row" if you don't know what the row terminator is?  Sounds like a chicken-and-egg problem to me.

Comment: Why do you want to know (OR) care what's the line separator is? it will be either `\r` or `\n` or `both` (Per MSDN). `ReadLine()` method will take care of that.

Comment: ReadLine() handles the terminator automatically, meaning it's not necessary to determine the EOL character for ReadLine to function and provide the first row. I need that EOL character that ReadLine() doesn't show because I have to pass it as a parameter into my Bulk Insert statement.

Comment: Your other option is to read character by character looking for what you have predefined as eol types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usual way to determine the end-of-line convention for a text file is to slurp in a buffer of sufficient size from the start of the file and examine it. The size of the buffer, of course, is somewhat dependent on the line length expected. You want to slurp in enough data to get a reasonable number of lines.

You are unlikely to encounter end-of-line conventions other than Windows (CR+LF), Unix/Linux/OS X (LF) or old-school MacOS (CR). For speed, it would be hard to beat something like this.

```
public enum EndOfLineStyle
{
  Unknown = 0     ,
  CR      = 1     ,
  LF      = 2     ,
  CRLF    = CR|LF ,
  Unix    = LF    ,
  MacOs   = CR    ,
  Windows = CRLF  ,
}

const int BUFFER_SIZE = 8192 ;
public EndOfLineStyle DetermineEndOfLineStyle( string pathToFile )
{
  int    bufl  = 0 ;
  char[] buf   = new char[BUFFER_SIZE] ;

  using ( StreamReader reader = File.OpenText( pathToFile ) )
  {
    bufl = reader.ReadBlock( buf , 0 , buf.Length ) ;
  }

  int crlfs = 0 ;
  int crs   = 0 ;
  int lfs   = 0 ;

  for ( int i = 0 ; i < bufl ; )
  {
    if      ( buf[i] == '\r' && i < bufl-1 && buf[i+1] == '\n' ) { ++crlfs ; i+=2 ; }
    else if ( buf[i] == '\r'                                   ) { ++crs   ; i+=1 ; }
    else if ( buf[i] == '\n' )                                   { ++lfs   ; i+=1 ; }
  }

  EndOfLineStyle style ;
  if      ( crlfs > crs   && crlfs > lfs ) style = EndOfLineStyle.Windows ;
  else if ( lfs   > crlfs && lfs   > crs ) style = EndOfLineStyle.Unix    ;
  else if ( crs   > crlfs && crs   > lfs ) style = EndOfLineStyle.MacOs   ;
  else                                     style = EndOfLineStyle.Unknown ;

  return style ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Nicholas. This is exactly what I was looking for (a solution that allowed me to partially read in the file and get the EOL).

Comment: The following code seems to produce an endless loop, telling me that the EOLs are not falling into Windows, Unix or Mac.   for ( int i = 0 ; i < bufl ; )
  {
    if      ( buf[i] == '\r' && i < bufl-1 && buf[i+1] == '\n' ) { ++crlfs ; i+=2 ; }
    else if ( buf[i] == '\r'                                   ) { ++crs   ; i+=1 ; }
    else if ( buf[i] == '\n' )                                   { ++lfs   ; i+=1 ; }
  }

Comment: Yes, because the loop only checks for \r and \n characters, the index variable does not get increased. Add else { i+=1;} inside the loop to fix this.